# Migrate/Backup sublime text 3 to another new mac

Tags: mac, sublime-text-3

How could I keep all `Sublime text 3` settings and packages to  my new Mac 
Thanks very much~~

It's too wasting time to install all packages and custimzed settings from scratch

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365948/how-to-save-restore-sublime-text-2-configs-plugins-to-migrate-to-another-compute and https://opensourcehacker.com/2013/05/09/exporting-and-sharing-sublime-text-configuration/ for Sublime Text 2 solutions, which are probably applicable to Sublime Text 3, as well.

Answer (score 2):

Just copy the whole files on `/Users/yourusername/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3` from your old mac to your new mac

Comment: Wow that just worked, thanks! This was driving me nuts on my Mac laptop for ages.

Comment: Glad if it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Slightly off-topic, but you could instead think about synchronizing your packages using Dropbox etc. See the [documentation](https://packagecontrol.io/docs/syncing) on the Package Control website for an example.